# creating a-z bar

Tags: c#, asp.net

below is the code i am using currently but wondering is there a better way of doing what i am doing... i am creating a-z model like A B C D E ....Z

any thoughts?

```
if (myEnum.MoveNext())
{
     MyNames t = myEnum.Current;

    if (t.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("a"))
    {
        if (_a == 0)
        {
            l = new Literal();
            //.....
            _a = 1;
        }
    }
    if (t.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("b"))
    {
        if (_b == 0)
        { 
            l = new Literal();
            l.Text = "<h1 id='B'><span>B</span></h1>" + Environment.NewLine;
            _b = 1;
        }
    }
   .....c..d...e...f...g....z
}
```

Comment: @Anthony edited my question and tag my question to "homework" but i dont see now, may be he removed

Comment: @Abu, I didn't add it, I only removed it. It was added by another user.

Comment: @Anthony, sorry about that i just see your name as last edited.

Comment: What are `_a` and `_b` supposed to represent in your code? They look like private variables or something. This question could use some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use "Aggregate" function provided with LINQ.

```
string[] list = { "a", "b", "c" };

var output = list.Aggregate("", (current, listitem) => current + (Environment.NewLine + "<h1 id='" + listitem.ToUpper() + "'><span>" + listitem.ToUpper() + "</span></h1>"));
```

Comment: i find this code much similar and what i needed based on my current setup.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are going using the collection's enumerator directly and hardcoding specific code for each letter. Presumably, output should be the same for each letter, with the only difference being the letter itself. I would scrap your current code and instead do something like the following.

```
// note: replace yourList with the correct collection variable
var distinctLetters = 
    yourList.Select(item => item.Name.Substring(0,1).ToUpper())
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(s => s);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string letter in distinctLetters)
{
    // build your output by Appending to the StringBuilder instance 
    string text = string.Format("<h1 id='{0}'><span>{0}</span></h1>" + Environment.NewLine, letter);
    builder.Append(text);
}

string output = builder.ToString(); // use output as you see fit
```

For a list containing the names `Alpha, Charlie, Delta, Alpha, Bravo`, the output will be

```
<h1 id='A'><span>A</span></h1>
<h1 id='B'><span>B</span></h1>
<h1 id='C'><span>C</span></h1>
<h1 id='D'><span>D</span></h1>
```

Comment: what is yourList and item going to be ? i try something like but did not work `var distinctLetters = t.Select(t.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()).Distinct();` because t is my enum list

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a typo, and I'll add a bit more clarification to the answer.

Comment: @Anthony: i dont have collection but i am just getting one row at a time, how would you do in that case?

Comment: @Abu, where did you get `myEnum`? As in `var myEnum = someObject.GetEnumerator();` What is *that* object's type?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linq GroupBy and group all of the names by the first letters.  Then you could quickly dump out the results.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple2